# How can I stream the raw JSON of each object from a large array of JSON objects?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Please note this is not a duplicate question as it is about **parsing** (and not deserializing) a large array object by object and retrieving the raw *JSON*.

I am dealing with very large arrays of *JSON* payload (tens of GB).

The structure of each object may be different i.e. heterogeneous:

```
[
    {"id": "foo", "value": "bar"},
    {"key": "foo", "name": "bar", "age": 10},
    ...
]
```

How can I go through the stream processing each object one at the time and **retrieve the raw *JSON* string of each object**?

My current solution is to use the `StreamReader` together with `JsonTextReader` to deserialize each object with a `JObject` and then retrieve the *JSON* using the `.ToString()`. But I prefer to avoid the performance cost and the *GC* allocation pressure of having to deserialize from *JSON* only to retrieve the *JSON* back again.

```
var file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Very.Large.Array.json");

using (var sr = new StreamReader(file.OpenRead()))
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
      var obj = JObject.Load(reader);      
      var rawJSON = obj.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Change your return type to IEnumerable<JObjevt€ and use yield return JObject.Load(...).  The performance will still be crap as the file is huge (JSON is not really a good streaming data format).

Comment: This does not answer my question, I am looking for a method of not having to deserialize the JSON to an object. My question is not about _yield returning_.

Comment: That’s why it’s a comment.  The answer is to change your file.

Comment: Is it safe to assume the file is formatted in any way? Like an object per line? Otherwise you'll have to consume the JSON character per character, to match braces to find objects.

Comment: It can be indented or not so I guess the _JSON_ must be parsed.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's not a duplicate, the other question (despite the title) is about deserializing objects which is what I am currently doing (as explained above) as opposed to parsing the raw _JSON_.

Comment: Fair enough. That said, you may want to consider reducing the amount of formatting you use. The repeated use of italics for the simple word JSON distracts from what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should use `JsonTextWriter` along with `JsonTextReader`. See below the simple POC class that demonstrates the idea.

I guess that some polishing is still required to bring this code to production quality. Like you may promote the `StringBuilder sb` from the local variable to the instance field and clear it at each iteration instead of creating new object.

But my goal was only to show the basic idea.

```
public class JsonBigFileReader
{
    static string ReadSingleObject(JsonTextReader reader)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                writer.WriteToken(reader, true);    //  writes current token including its children (meaning the whole object)
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ReadArray(string fileName)
    {
        var file = new FileInfo(fileName);
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(file.OpenRead()))
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            reader.Read();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    yield return ReadSingleObject(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```